# Who get comments from post group with Facebook API

Tags: python, facebook, api

I try to get the comments of a post from a group that I am a member (only member) and that by the way, the group is closed, but it does not return anything ..

I try it this way: {postid}/comments

[image]

I really do not know if you're allowed what I'm trying to do. What if you let me get is information about the videos that have been posted in the group.

I have never used the Facebook API before, so I know very little about the topic.

Comment: You need to be admin of the group

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right facebook api allows you to programmatically access content of only public groups. To get data from private/closed groups you need to be admin, as user @WizKid pointed out

Comment: Web scraping would be the solution?

Comment: I don't think that will scale. But you can surely try with `selenium` or `phantomjs`